# ¿Como puedo evitar la duplicidad de información al hacer un 'insert into' con php y mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Tengo el siguiente código, que inserta datos de un archivo csv en una tabla de mysql:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password, $basededatos);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Conectado correctamente<br>";
if (($fichero = fopen("archivo.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $row = 0;
    while (($datos = fgetcsv($fichero, 1000)) !== FALSE) {
        if (4 <= $row){
        echo $datos[0];
        echo $datos[2];
        mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO fecha_hora(s_codigo_cf, fecha, valor) VALUES ('010101', '$datos[0]', '$datos[2]')");}        
        $row++;
    }
}mysqli_close($conn);
```

¿Como puedo evitar la duplicidad de información, tomando en cuenta que mi tabla no la trabajo con datos únicos ni auto-increment?.

Lo que creo se debe hacer, es usar una sentencia que compare los 3 valores con los de mi tabla (que los 3 sean exactamente iguales) y si no existen los inserte, sino, los salte.

¿Como puedo hacer eso?.

Comment: Que valores no se pueden repetir?

Comment: Tu creencia es correcta, haz una consulta para verificar si los datos existen. Al menos inténtalo y, si algo falla, con gusto te ayudamos.

Comment: Aparte de verificar por código si un registro existe antes de insertarlo, deberías poner también en la tabla una restricción del tipo  `UNIQUE` para evitar duplicados. Eso sería resolver el problema realmente de raíz. Esa responsabilidad no la puedes delegar solamente en el código PHP.

Comment: Finalmente lo solucioné haciendo lo comentado por @Triby . Más abajo la respuesta y el código. Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Lo solucioné!

Lo que hice fue generar un query que integre un if para consultar si la combinación de los valores existia o no, de no ser asi que siga con el insert.

Así quedó el código:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password, $basededatos);    
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}    
echo "Conectado correctamente<br>";    
if (($fichero = fopen("archivo.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $row = 0;
    while (($datos = fgetcsv($fichero, 1000)) !== FALSE) {
        echo $row;
        if (4 <= $row) {
            $resultado = $conn->query("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM fecha_hora WHERE s_codigo_cf='010101' AND fecha='$datos[0]');");
            $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado);    
            if ($row2[0] == "1") {    
                echo "Existe";
            } else {
                mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO fecha_hora(s_codigo_cf, fecha, valor) VALUES ('010101', '$datos[0]', '$datos[2]')");    
            }                
        }$row++;
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```